# Angular 2 way binding in video play event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My 2 way bidning doesn't work, it works if i call the vm.Play() function directly but when it gets called from the video play event then it doesn't work. Does anyone know why?

```
function VideoEventStats() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            videoEventStats: "="
        },
        controller: controllerFunction,
        controllerAs: "vm",
        bindToController: true
    };

    controllerFunction.$inject = ["$element"];

    function controllerFunction($element) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.Play = Play;

        if($element.context.tagName === "VIDEO") {

            angular.element($element).on('play', vm.Play);

            $element.context.onended = function() {
                console.log('ended..');
            };
        }
        else {
            console.warn('This element is not a video element');
        }

        function Play() {
            vm.videoEventStats.CurrentUserHasSeen = true;
        }
    }

    return directive;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the vm.videoEventStats.CurrentUserHasSeen = true; inside of a $timeout made the trick...

```
function Play() { $timeout(function() { vm.videoEventStats.CurrentUserHasSeen = true; }, 0); }
```